# Linq Where/OrderBy string to int

Tags: c#, .net, linq, nhibernate

I have seen similar questions on here but none of the answers are working for my linq query.

I am trying to convert a string to integer on the `.ThenBy()`

```
dbResults = gaResultDetails.All
.Where(c => c.ContentLink.Id == contentId && c.RequestType.Id == requestTypeId)
.OrderBy(c => c.DateFrom)
.ThenBy(c => int.Parse(c.Data_2)).Take(Take).ToList();
```

Please note I am using nHibernate for data access and with the above expression get the following error:

```
[NotSupportedException: Int32 Parse(System.String)]
```

Help!

Comment: What does `gaResultDetails.All` returns?

Comment: The problem I think is the NHibernate does not support this cast in the order methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some functions are not supported by the nhibernate linq expression builder, try this:

```
dbResults = gaResultDetails.All
  .Where(c => c.ContentLink.Id == contentId && c.RequestType.Id == requestTypeId)    
  .AsEnumerable()
  .OrderBy(c => c.DateFrom)
  .ThenBy(c => int.Parse(c.Data_2))
  .Take(Take) 
  .ToList();
```

Might not be ideal performance-wise, but should accomplish what you need.

Comment: You can use `AsEnumerable()` instead of `ToArray()` to avoid allocating the extra array.

Comment: @mxmissile Perfect! The query only returns a very small data set so performance in this instance shouldn't cause a problem but shall bear this in mind in the future. Thank you

Comment: It is a solution but it is not good. Methods like `AsEnumerable()`, `ToList()` provides all results in memory and the order and take will be performed in memory instead only the results in `Take(Take)` values on query.

Comment: @FelipeOriani correct Take is supported by nhibernate, and fixed.

Comment: Still not provide the solution the OP wants because the order would be in the memory only in the values which take results, despising the values that could be provided by Order methods. I think the question here is how to cast the value in the `ThenBy` method. I think NHibernate does not support it.

Comment: @FelipeOriani ouch! you are right, the desired take would depend on the order, I've been bit by this before. I think OP is going to have to drop down to raw SQL.

Comment: @Webb warning, this answer is not going to give the desired results unless you move the `Take` to after the `AsEnumerable()` which could kill performance as @FelipeOriani indicated above. Edit: I edited the answer to reflect this.

Comment: What is the recommend answer, don't use nHibernate? haha

Comment: It really depends on the dataset, if your `where` filters it down to a manageable amount, the extra in memory filter should not be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a shot in the dark.  If the parse doesn't work in the ThenBy, it probably won't in the `let` but it's worth a shot. In LINQ syntax, cuz I like it better:

```
dbResults = (from c in gaResultDetails.All
             where c.ContentLink.Id == contentId 
              && c.RequestType.Id == requestTypeId
             let nData2 = int.Parse(c.Data_2)
             orderby c.DateFrom, nData2) 
           .Take(Take) 
           .ToList();
```

Answer (score -1):

It seems like your ORM tries to perform casting on the SQL server side.
Try to evaluate data before casting, e.g. :

```
dbResults = gaResultDetails.All
.Where(c => c.ContentLink.Id == contentId && c.RequestType.Id == requestTypeId)
.OrderBy(c => c.DateFrom).ToList()
.ThenBy(c => int.Parse(c.Data_2)).Take(Take).ToList();
```

Comment: You cant call ThenBy() on a IList.